# Apple App SKU: How do I view and change SKUs?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, skus

When I go into iTunes connect and create a placeholder for a new App, it asks me for SKU.

It seems that I can pick a number out of the blue to use.

However, where can I find SKUs for my existing apps?   I can't find this information anywhere!!!

And where can I change them?  Can I?  For my first couple of apps I just put in some random number to get past to the next screen.   but can I subsequently reorganize everything?

Yet again the attempt to navigate through Apple's application deployment process has left me  in a state of frustration and bewilderment.

Answer (score 8):

If I click on "Manage You Applications" I see a list of both my iOS and Mac OS applications. Clicking on one of those brings me to the summary page for that application. This summary page lists the SKU, Bundle ID, and Apple ID for the application. This is true even for an app that is not yet available for sale.

As to changing it I do not see any way to do that and my suspicion is that you cannot. The SKU is used to identify the app so I believe the intent is that it should stay the same over the lifetime of the app.

Also, if you check the developer forums and search for SKU you will see several people saying that you cannot use a SKU again so that would reinforce the idea that they cannot be changed for an app once they have been set.

Answer (score 3):

The SKU can not be changed and the Bundle ID can only be changed before the submission of the 1st build.

Comment: Bundle ID can be changed before 1st build submission.

Answer (score 3):

In the updated ITC you must go to "My Apps" - Choose the app you want to see the information. Click on the "More" menu item - "About This App" where you will find:

Primary Language 
Bundle ID
Apple ID
SKU